# Different DISTINCT COUNT results on same record set

Tags: mysql

I have strange behavior of two nearly identical 'count' queries that should return same results.

This query returns **correct** count result: **2006**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT c0_.campaign_activity_user_id) AS sclr0
FROM campaign_activities c0_
WHERE c0_.campaign_id = 5539 
    AND c0_.campaign_activity_user_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND c0_.campaign_activity_user_id <> ''
    AND c0_.campaign_activity_timestamp >= '2017-07-13 00:00:00' 
    AND c0_.campaign_activity_timestamp <= '2017-08-14 23:59:59';
```

explain:
[image: EXPLAIN]

---

This query returns **incorrect** result: **1490**

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT c0_.campaign_activity_user_id) AS sclr0
FROM campaign_activities c0_
WHERE c0_.campaign_id = 5539
    AND c0_.campaign_activity_user_id IS NOT NULL
    AND c0_.campaign_activity_user_id <> '';
```

explain:
[image: EXPLAIN]

I have manually counted rows and second query **should** return same result as first (**2006**) but it doesn't which I don't understand.

It seems that if I add another 'AND' condition to second query which should haven't any impact on result, it sudenly returns right count (2006), e.g. if I add `AND c0_.campaign_activity_timestamp is not null`; EVERY record HAS some timestamp so it has not any impact on count, but it now returns right result (2006), which is strange.

DDL

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_activities` (
  `campaign_activity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `campaign_link_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_activity_user_id` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_activity_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `campaign_activity_ip` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_activity_proxy` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_activity_http_referer` text COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
  `campaign_activity_method` enum('curl','socket') COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_activity_legitimate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_referer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`campaign_activity_id`,`campaign_id`),
  KEY `fk_reference_35` (`campaign_id`),
  KEY `fk_reference_36` (`campaign_link_id`),
  KEY `fk_reference_37` (`campaign_referer_id`),
  KEY `campaign_activity_user_id` (`campaign_activity_user_id`),
  KEY `campaign_id_campaign_activity_user_id` (`campaign_id`,`campaign_activity_user_id`),
  KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`,`campaign_link_id`,`campaign_activity_user_id`,`campaign_activity_timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=28608046 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_czech_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT COMMENT='ex. tabulka kampane_statist'
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (campaign_id)
PARTITIONS 1024 */;
```

Do you know, where could be a problem, please?
Thank you very much.

EDIT:
forgot to mension, that according to EXPLAIN, second query seems to be automatically grouping results, but it makes no sense to me (regarding the fact, there is no explicit group by)

Comment: Why does the explain think there is a group by?

Comment: Exactly, it also confuses me and I dont know why it should automatically grouping results.

Comment: What is your mysql version? There are some known bugs with partitions and multi column primary keys, although I'm not sure if they fit here, but if you have an old version, it might be such a bug. You could try to drop and recreate the `campaign_activity_user_id`-index. Do both queries limit themselves to the right partition? (`explain partitions ...`). Is it possible to check which values are omitted? (E.g. in case it also happens when you do `SELECT DISTINCT c0_.campaign_activity_user_id FROM campaign_activities c0_ ...`)